# Apply Service call for every element in the list, and return only one list with RXJava

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a method that does a call to Firebase. This method accepts a date and returns an observable.

Then I have an array of dates, that will be used as parameter of this firebase call.

I need to call the method once per item in the array, and finally concatenate to a one list.

But I don't know how to achieve it.

I'm trying to do something like:

```
for (dateToRetrieve in listOfDatesToRetrieve) {
            val subscription = FireBaseUtils.getEventsForMap(dateToRetrieve)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .subscribe { retrievedEventsForMap ->

                        val eventsList: MutableList<Event> = retrievedEventsForMap
                        eventListWithNoDuplicatesTotal.addAll(eventsList)

                        var eventListWithNoDuplicates = eventListWithNoDuplicatesTotal.distinctBy { it -> it.eventID }
                        this.presenter.onEventsRetrieved(eventListWithNoDuplicates as MutableList<Event>)
                       }
            this.presenter.addSubscription(subscription)
        }
```

But I know that is not the best solution because I'm sending the calls one by one, and adding to the list.

Is there any possibility to do it and return 1 result with the combination of all the calls?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
val subscription =  Observable.fromIterable(listOfDatesToRetrieve)
        .flatMap(dateToRetrieve -> FireBaseUtils.getEventsForMap(dateToRetrieve))
        .flatMapIterable { item -> item }
        .toList()
        .distinct { it -> it.eventID }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe { list ->
            this.presenter.onEventsRetrieved(list as MutableList<Event>)
        }
this.presenter.addSubscription(subscription)
```

Comment: But, with this solution I got N differents list of data (one per item on listOfDatesToRetrieve), so presenter is called N tims. But what I need is send to the present only 1 list with all the results merges. And I' dont know how to do it.